# What do you call the act of preventing someone of entering the wrong password many times?

Tags: word-request

What do you call the act of preventing someone of entering the wrong password many times? Sometimes, you get blocked after 5 attempts, what do programmers call the feature of APIs of preventing the number of tries before locking users out the system?

Comment: What do you call it? In your language?  Have you tried a bilingual dictionary?

Comment: An attack in form of repeated password entries is called a [brute-force attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brute-force_attack).You could derive the feature name from it e.g. 'brute-force attack prevention'.

Answer (score 3):

**Lockout** or **account lockout** is the name for the practice of blocking further login attempts after a certain number of invalid attempts.

> Account lockout is a useful method for slowing down online password-guessing attacks as well as to compensate for weak password policies. These three policies work together to limit the number of consecutive, within a period of time, logon attempts that fail due to a bad password. [Ultimate Windows Security](https://www.ultimatewindowssecurity.com/wiki/page.aspx?spid=AccountLockout)

> The Account lockout threshold policy setting determines the number of failed sign-in attempts that will cause a user account to be locked. [Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/account-lockout-threshold)

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to call it is *account block* after *X* attempts. There is no *one word* for that as far as I know. So,

> Add a feature of *account block* ...

Yes, it further requires clarification of blocking the account because of *unsuccessful attempts...* or something like that.